# Is it true that every commutative ring with unity and finitely many maximal ideals can be written as finite direct product of local rings?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Is it true that every commutative ring with unity and finitely many maximal ideals can be written as direct product of local rings?

Comment: Add zero-dimensional and get a correct claim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theoretical detail to this problem is that while a ring with finitely many maximal ideals is [*semilocal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-local_ring), a finite product of local rings is [*semiperfect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_ring).

A semiperfect ring is semilocal, but there is a gap between the two notions, namely that a semiperfect ring is a semilocal ring in which idempotents lift modulo the Jacobson radical.

Now, given an integral domain with two or more maximal ideals, it is easy to produce another integral domain (which isn't a product of any two nonzero rings) which has two maximal ideals. You simply take two maximal ideals $M_1, M_2$, and "localize" at the multiplicative set $S=(R\setminus M_1)\cap (R\setminus M_2)$.  The images of $M_1$ and $M_2$ in the localization are guaranteed to be the only two maximal ideals.

Comment: The localization example is, of course, just a more formal description of the specific example Lord Shark gave: $S^{-1}\mathbb Z$ where $S=\mathbb Z\setminus (2)\cap \mathbb Z\setminus (3)$. I hadn't ever seen the particular description of it before, and it took me a minute or two to see why the primes greater than $2$ and $3$ which aren't $1\pmod 6$ are also invertible!

Comment: $5\in S$ and yet $5\ne 1+6b$. However your example works as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about
$$R=\{a/(1+6b):a,b\in\Bbb Z\}?$$
This has two maximal ideals, generated by $2$ and $3$, yet is indecomposable (only idempotents are $\pm1$).